# How to prove the norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

> Show that if $||T||<1$ and $x^k$ is a sequence defined by $x^{k}=Tx^{k-1}+c$ 
>   where $c$ is a given vector,
>
> we have $||x-x^{k}||\le \dfrac{||T||^k}{1-||T||}(||x^{1}-x^{0}||,x\in \Bbb R^n$

Now $||x^{2}-x^{1}||=||T(x^{1})-T(x^0)||\le||T||||x^{1}-x^{0}||$

$||x^{3}-x^{2}||=||T(x^{2})-T(x^1)||\le||T||^2||x^{1}-x^{0}||$
and so on..

In general

$||x^{k}-x^{k-1}||=||T(x^{k-1})-T(x^{k-2})||\le||T||^{k-1}||x^{1}-x^{0}||$

Adding all we get

$||x^{k}-x^{1}||=||T(x^{k-1})-T(x^{k-2})||\le\{||T||+||T||^2+\cdots +||T||^{k-1}\}||x^{1}-x^{0}||$

I understand the series on the RHS converges but I dont understand how to arrive at the given inequality

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 1):

This is just the sum of a geometric progression:
$$\|x^k-x^1\|\le\frac{\|T\|-\|T\|^k}{1-\|T\|}\|x^1-x^0\|.$$
Letting $k\to\infty$,
$$\|x-x^1\|\le\frac{\|T\|}{1-\|T\|}\|x^1-x^0\|$$
which is the $k=1$ case of what you seek.

In general, for $r>k$
$$\|x^r-x^k\|\le\frac{\|T\|^k-\|T\|^r}{1-\|T\|}\|x_1-x_0\|,$$
and therefore
$$\|x-x^k\|\le\frac{\|T\|^k}{1-\|T\|}\|x_1-x_0\|$$
in the limit as $r\to\infty$.

Comment: Two questions:(1) how do you know that $\lim x^k$ converges and it equals $x$

Comment: and (2) i dont  understand the case for $k>r$

Comment: What is $x$, other than $\lim x^k$? Anyway these formulae show that the sequence is Cauchy, and so will converge in a complete space. @Join_PhD

Comment: I don't think there is any justification for the assumption  that $x =\lim x^{k}$ but $x^{0}=x$ is reasonable assumption.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown,Thank you but can you kindly explain the case $k>r$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown,can you kindly explain the case when $k>r$ ,I dont understand it

Comment: @Join_PhD It's pretty much the same as the argument you give.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown;But i dont get it